# Should I use custom model binder to bind view model to entity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, model-view-controller, mvvm, custom-model-binder

Just some idea to make more use of custom model binder. I am currently still using IMapper  interface to do so, though wondering whether part of the purpose of custom binder is to mapping view model or input model to business entity? I can see there might be some limitations if i use MVC custom binder. What is the advantage to use the custom binder in MVC?   Will my app gain better performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer would be **No, you should not**

`ModelBinder` by itself is part of ASP.NET MVC infrastructure. If you would take a look at ASP.NET MVC pipline [(PDF)](http://www.simple-talk.com/content/file.ashx?file=6068) you would see that it's job is
to convert a posted web form data (a string basically) or query string from URL to an instance of particular class.
ASP.NET MVC framework has a [DefaultModelBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) that
is suitable for 99% of cases. Custom model binders could be used in situations where standard data conversion fails e.g. mapping `$ 1,234.56` from a textbox to a `decimal` value of `1234.56`

Moreover `ModelBinder` implements `IModelBinder` interface with a single [BindModel()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.imodelbinder.bindmodel%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) method. This method expects parameters that would be hard to 'hand-craft' to make any use of them and are totally not relevant to your scenario.

What you are realy looking for is
 - *either* custom object mapping between viewmodels and business objects where you manually assign one object property values to another
 - *or* taking advantage of libs/frameworks such as [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) or [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) which take care of object mapping hassle away from you
 - or a mix of both

Comment: Thanks heaps @Ramunas, luckily I use mapper instead. I used automapper a bit, but later on chose not to for maintenance and performance considerations.  More important, the pipeline PDF is extermely valueable and I will share it with my team.